# System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurs after call to DirectoryEntry()

Tags: c#

I am debugging a small C# app that I just wrote. The app seems to run fine on my development box but throws the following errors when run on other machines (all machines are windows 7 pro x64 w/ .net 4 installed):

```
    Application: WolApp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at WolApp.PowerModel..ctor()
   at WolApp.PowerController..ctor()
   at WolApp.Program.Main()
```

A second error succeeds this one from kernelbase.dll, but, one thing at a time....

From the stack trace it seems that the unhandled exception is being throwin inside of the PowerModel constructor, which consists only of this:

```
public PowerModel() {
entry = new DirectoryEntry();
}
```

Where entry is a field of the PowerModel class. I have since added the following try catch block

```
 public PowerModel() {
            try
            {
                entry = new DirectoryEntry();
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                string sSource;
                string sLog;
                string sEvent;

                sSource = "WolApp";
                sLog = "Application";
                sEvent = e.Message;
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource,sLog);
                EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent);
             }
        }
```

Yet the same exception is still thrown (and only on external machines)?

Also, an additional message appears in the log from Windows Error Reporting, as follows:

```
 1745074215 
   5 
   CLR20r3 
   Not available 
   0 
   wolapp.exe 
   1.0.0.0 
   4d657be0 
   WolApp 
   1.0.0.0 
   4d657be0 
   3 
   26 
   System.IO.FileNotFoundException 

   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\WERC3EF.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml 
   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_wolapp.exe_62bdee217c82fa90fcdaeb137c1659c897785b85_20036868 

   0 
   ce7dc05c-3f93-11e0-8907-0024e82e58f8 
   0
```

Answer (score 3):

`DirectoryEntry` is a class from the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace and deals with entries in an Active Directory.

It has nothing whatsoever to do with an entry in the directory on disk ... I am most surprised you would get a `FileNotFoundExeption` with this...

*(not applicable)*

<strike>Or if it's *not* the `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` you're talking about, then it's an **extremely** bad choice of a class name for this class!</strike>

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I am attempting to use System.DirectoryServices.

Comment: @dilzniksan: what I'm wondering is what you'd create a `DirectoryEntry` object instance without specifying an LDAP path for that object...

Comment: Working with DirectoryEntry myself, I am encountering FNF Exception from calls at the interop boundary. But... the line-thru comment is most salient - is the question even regarding the DirectoryServices namespace??

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this issue, but something similar appears [here on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/e38434e7-1e9f-4ee6-9be4-6f52203d674c), with a fix.

**EDIT** I just re-read your error message, and this bit jumped out:

```
CLR20r3 
   Not available
```

Do the other machines have .Net 2.0 installed? The `FileNotFoundException` sounds like it cannot find the CLR.

[This link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/systemcenteressentials/thread/a4374953-0b0f-4c87-b5d4-6e8e845eac9b) describes another issue (with resolution) similar to your problem.

Comment: I got excited when I found that article too, but I don't believe its applicable. Specifically, the error they received was

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The network path was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070035)

Whereas the error I received within my application does not seem to have any specifying information.

Comment: All machines are running .NET 4.0.30319.

I am disinclined to think the second issue is applicable either; DirectoryEntry() seems to be generating an error before it is provided with any credentials (that is before it attempts to connect to any DCs).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not very relevant, but I face the same issue with the error message being totally  unspecific. Here is the error that I received

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-16T08:38:12.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>8249</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>ADCOWDPTEST1</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Application: Well Abandonment Automation.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException Stack: at WA.Client.RequestList.InitializeComponent() at WA.Client.RequestList..ctor() at WA.Client.Program.Main()</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

After a little digging around, I discovered I was referencing third party Dlls that was installed on my development machine and not installed on the server.